# Send MMS (can't load image)

Tags: android, mms

This code works for "adress" and "sms_body" but not for "image"

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Uri uri=Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/q.png");
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.putExtra("address","1234567890");
        i.putExtra("sms_body","This is the text mms");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,"file:/"+uri);
        i.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(i);

    }   
}
```

Someone knows why ?

Comment: Do you get any error ? Make sure your image is located at the specified path only.

Comment: yes my image is located here "file://storage/extSdCard/Download/q.png"

Comment: now push another image from your computer into this folder and try

Comment: i do it and there is nothing :\

Comment: could you test this into your Emulator or some real device?? and you inserted SDcard into your device right?

Comment: yes i tested it on a real device (samsung ace 2)

Comment: and you inserted SDcard into your device right?

Comment: Yeees but in "File Explorer" he found nothing on my sdcard

Comment: Here i think  your sdcard not mounted successfully.

Comment: so only one solution out you can add images into other location in sdcard and try

Comment: no now it's ok i can read all my files in sdcard not in mnt->sdcard but in storage>extSdCard>download

Comment: now you only change the file path into Uri and test it. if it's work then accepts my answer

Comment: i did Uri uri=Uri.parse("file://storage/extSdCard/download/q.png"); and i does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. The solution is to use :

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(file));
```

Instead of :

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
```

I thank all those who wanted to help me :)

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,"file:/"+uri);
```

instead of you just passed uri into

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
```

try this is working in my case.

Comment: i tried it now and it does not work. my file path "file://storage/extSdCard/Download/q.png"

Comment: you add sdcard permission into your manifest.xml file. cross check it and/or if your image size more the>1MB then you need to create bitmap and then add into EXTRA_STREAM

Comment: yes i added this 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

And my image size ="47,6 Ko"

Comment: also add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and check

Comment: it is very strange becoz it's perfectly working in my case and i have added only WRITE_PERMISSION

Comment: hey i found one issue: you provide your uri like this: Uri uri=Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/q.png");

Comment: you must mention your "Download" folder into your path:Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/yourfilename"

Comment: I tried again. Image is not downloaded but I no longer have the error "file is not supported"

Comment: we are very near to solve.. ok now, you can test with any Email attachment or Message

Comment: i can't open it with Email. It is opened automatically with MMS

Comment: but when? i mean at activity start-up time or at any button click event?

Comment: i tried with hotmail. the email is sent but no image attachement

Comment: Here i made the same situation now, i can display one snap of DDMS where my image be located.

Comment: it's very strange, when i want to send email i see the image attachement but the size = 0

Comment: test with Gmail or Messages?? just for testing

Answer (score 2):

**Create bitmap first**

```
ImageView img_user= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_user);

Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(img_user.getWidth(),img_user.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

img_user.draw(new Canvas(screenshot));

**Get your image path**

```
String path = "file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/q.png";
```

**Use path in URI class**

```
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);
```

**Call Intent**

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
emailIntent.setType("image/png");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the all structure of my sdcard and image be located at your mentioned path:
[image: DDMS show file location]

Comment: So I do not understand why it does not work for me :\

Comment: give me your app name where you want to attach this file..I want to know why this is happen?

Comment: look the image that i posted (when i click on "file explorer" i see nothing in my sdcard)